# Como borrar de tabla cuando se quita el select del chekcbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

lo que pasa que al seleccionar un item carga sus datos en una tabla, como puedo hacer para que cuando le quite el select se borren de la tabla

Digamo, primero seleccione el item
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego , le quito el select del checkbox y en vez de borrarse se agrega de nuevo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacerle para que al quitar el select del checkbox se borre el item de la tabla.

Archivo del cuadro donde selecciono el checkbox

```
   folfiscal = data['datos_tabla'][index]['foliofiscal'];
                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
                        cell7.innerHTML ='<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="leer[]"   onclick="javascript:return LLenarTablaconcepto(\''+folfisc+'\')"/>'+folfisc+'</td>';
```

A continuacion dejo el codigo

```
function LLenarTablaconcepto(folfisc)
    {

        //alert('#folfisc');
      $.ajax({
            data: {"folfisc":$("#folfisc").val()},
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json", //tipo de datos que devuelve json
            url: "consulta_facturas_concepto.php?foliofiscal="+folfisc,
            success: function(data)
            {
                //if( data.folio != 0 )
                if( data.encontrado != 0 )
                {
                    var id=0;
                    $(data['datos_tabla']).each(function(index)
                    {


                        var table = document.getElementById('tablaExterior').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);



                        var cell0= row.insertCell(0);
                         var folio = data['datos_tabla'][index]['descripcion'];

                        cell0.innerHTML ='<td bgcolor="blue" align="center"><a href=javascript:conceptos_erp(\''+rowCount+'\') >'+folio+'</a></td>';

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                        cell2.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['valorunitario'];

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                        cell3.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['cantidad'];

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                        cell4.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['importe'];

                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                        cell5.innerHTML   = "";

                    id++;
                    });

                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }
             }

        });
    return true;
  }
```

Donde específicamente aquí se encuentra donde llama al javascript

```
cell0.innerHTML ='<td bgcolor="blue" align="center"><a href=javascript:conceptos_erp(\''+rowCount+'\') >'+folio+'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver si comprendo, quieres actualizar la tabla con registros subministrados poor el select? si es asi solo debe vaciar la tabla cada ver que es llamada la funcion **LLenarTablaconcepto**

```js
function LLenarTablaconcepto(folfisc)
    {

        //alert('#folfisc');
      $.ajax({
            data: {"folfisc":$("#folfisc").val()},
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json", //tipo de datos que devuelve json
            url: "consulta_facturas_concepto.php?foliofiscal="+folfisc,
            success: function(data)
            {
                //if( data.folio != 0 )
                if( data.encontrado != 0 )
                {
                    var id=0;
                    var table = document.getElementById('tablaExterior').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                    table.innerHTML = '';
                    $(data['datos_tabla']).each(function(index)
                    {**texto en negrita**
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                        var cell0= row.insertCell(0);
                         var folio = data['datos_tabla'][index]['descripcion'];

                        cell0.innerHTML ='<td bgcolor="blue" align="center"><a href=javascript:conceptos_erp(\''+rowCount+'\') >'+folio+'</a></td>';

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                        cell2.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['valorunitario'];

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                        cell3.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['cantidad'];

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                        cell4.innerHTML =  data['datos_tabla'][index]['importe'];

                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                        cell5.innerHTML   = "";

                    id++;
                    });

                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }
             }

        });
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Asi es, como le hago para vaciar la tabla me puedes ayudar